# Issues while booting up my PC

Tags: boot, display

The PC is turning on, but the monitor is showing 3 colors instead: red, green, and blue simultaneously.

I tried pressing `F10` after which I can hear the beep like it is going into BIOS, but the monitor is not showing anything different.

I've tried plugging another monitor, but with no results. What could be the problem?

P.S.: My PC is an HP ProOne 400 G2, the PC and the monitor are the same device.

Comment: Most likely a faulty video card, rather than a problem with the monitors. Have you tried replacing your video card? And also, give us more information about your hardware: motherboard, videocard, power supply, and etc.

Comment: Here is your support page for the ProOne you have, they have a service manual in case you need to open it up to replace something.....https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-proone-400-g2-20-inch-touch-all-in-one-pc/7638343/manuals